# Why can't I change the value of variable after applying if-else condition?

Tags: python, django

I have initialized a variable "stocks" and I want to change its value if that particular condition exists but when I do this in a function inside python file, it returns same initialised value "0". I have done this many times in a python script, but I am not able to apply in this script which is part of Django app. So if I can't do this in this way what are the other ways to do this. 
Code of that file is below:

```
# views.py file
def data(request, stocks_id, choice_id):
    stocks = 0
    selected_stock = Stocks.objects.get(id=stocks_id)
    selected_symbol = selected_stock.symbol
    strng = ""
    symbol = selected_symbol + strng
    if choice_id == 1:
        stocks = Get_Quote(symbol)
    elif choice_id == 2:
        stocks = Get_percent_change(symbol)
    return render(request, 'stocks/data.html', {"stocks": stocks})
```

Comment: My guess is that you never change the value of `stocks` because `choice_id` is not 1 or 2. Have you tried using a debugger and investigate the other variables?

Comment: @Constantinius Yeah now I got it. Parameters of views return string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters of the views are always strings.  So you have to use the string comparison in the `if` condition:

```
if choice_id == "1":
    stocks = Get_Quote(symbol)
elif choice_id == "2":
    stocks = Get_percent_change(symbol)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I know it returns string.

Answer (score 1):

Your if conditions are never true so it never changes stocks. The reason is that stocks_id, coming as it does from the url, is a string not a number. So you should say `"1"` instead of just `1`.

Try something like this:

```
def data(request, stocks_id, choice_id):
    stocks = 0
    selected_stock = Stocks.objects.get(id=stocks_id)
    selected_symbol = selected_stock.symbol
    strng = ""
    symbol = selected_symbol + strng
    if choice_id == "1":
        stocks = Get_Quote(symbol)
    elif choice_id == "2":
        stocks = Get_percent_change(symbol)
    return render(request, 'stocks/data.html', {"stocks": stocks})
```